# Android - Location Tracking not returning locations for large periods of time

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

I am building an app that tracks users over long distances (hours of driving). It works but I am getting areas (30mins plus) where nothing is tracked at all.

I have tried adding a wakelock to fix this but to no avail.. so I am thinking it isn't changing providers correctly?

public class ActiveJobActivity extends Activity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener  {

```
// Milliseconds per second
private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
// Update frequency in seconds
public static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 10;
// Update frequency in milliseconds
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
// The fastest update frequency, in seconds
private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 10;
// A fast frequency ceiling in milliseconds
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL =
        MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;

// vars..

// Define an object that holds accuracy and frequency parameters
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
LocationClient mLocationClient;
boolean mUpdatesRequested;


protected PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock; 
LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    this.mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Wakelock");

    mWakeLock.acquire();


}

/* Prevent app from being killed on back */
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    // Back?
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Back
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        // Return
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {

    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_active_job);

    if(mLocationRequest == null){
        //Create LocationRequest object.
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        // Use high accuracy
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        // Set the update interval to 5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        // Set the fastest update interval to 1 second
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    }
   /* Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to
    * handle callbacks.
    */
   if(mLocationClient == null){
       mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
       mUpdatesRequested = true;
   }

   if(!mLocationClient.isConnected()){
       mLocationClient.connect();
   }
    mUpdatesRequested = true;
}

 /*
 * Handle results returned to the FragmentActivity
 * by Google Play services
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Decide what to do based on the original request code
    switch (requestCode) {
        case CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST :
        /*
         * If the result code is Activity.RESULT_OK, try
         * to connect again
         */
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK :
                /*
                 * Try the request again
                 */
                break;
            }
    }
}   

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                    this,
                    CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            /*
            * Thrown if Google Play services cancelled the original
            * PendingIntent
            */
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Log the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

    }       
}



@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mUpdatesRequested) {
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // add locaiton to db.
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(provider.equals("LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER")){
        Log.i("Active Job Location", "GPS Disabled");
    }
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    } else {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }
    mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    } else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }
    mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mWakeLock.isHeld())
    {
    this.mWakeLock.release();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Hey, I also faced the same issue with Google Play Location Services. This is not your code issue. However you have to check with google map that, you are getting location over there or not?

Comment: If you are not getting location on Goolge Map application also then just enable location services and restart your device. It should work.

Comment: This isn't the issue, i have tested it on both phones. Nothing to do with Google Maps - that works fine.

Comment: But are you able to get location on Google map? As the library you are using is the same which is used by Google Map APP

Comment: Yes I am, Google Map works fine. Most of my tracking on my own app works. Just some large areas where it doesnt work at all.